# Cannot reset Laptop BIOS on Toshiba L50D-B-136

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords

I currently have a Toshiba laptop which has come into the office with a BIOS password on, this laptop is our property and someone has added a password onto the BIOS.

The normal passwords such as "Toshiba" and leaving it blank does not not work and I cannot boot into Windows to remove the password as the laptop needs to have the time set via the BIOS for it to continue booting.

The laptop model is a Toshiba L50D-B-136

Thank You!

[Laptop Motherboard Layout, in case anyone can see jumper pins etc, can provide better photos if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBbxb.jpg)

Comment: If it is still under warranty you can contact toshiba support they can help you, after providing proof of ownership+serial number or give you instructions to get a number they need to be able to help you. 
Some older models can be bypassed by using https://bios-pw.org/  you have to provide a serial or tag number , some L models can be done by a hardware hack described here: https://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/bios-reset-on-toshiba-satellite IT IS ALWAYS better if you call toshiba if you can.

Comment: From the photo you postet it seems that the bios/cmos battery could be on the other side. Assuming the device it's still dismounted.

Answer (score -1):

Can you remove the cmos battery, then remove the main battery, hold power button down for 20 sec, then boot back up?  The cmos battery typically saves settings like a bios pw.

Comment: This would be better served as a comment to the question.  Consider modifying this answer and provide specifics on how the author solves their problem in detail